# Display AlertDialog onLongClick

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, android-alertdialog, onlongclicklistener

I have a listView and a onClickListener that onClick do som things and it works. Now I want to display an AlertDialog onLongClick but nothing happens. I've added `android:longClickable="true"` to the ListView in the manifest too but still, nothing happens.

```
listView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        final CharSequence[] items = {"Revansch!", "Lägg till som vän","Ta bort spelet"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChallengeList.this);

        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        return true;

    }

});
```

Anyone know why it's not working? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, final long id) {

       final CharSequence[] items = {"Revansch!", "Lägg till som vän","Ta bort spelet"};
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChallengeList.this);
       builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this. Its working.

```
myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
            return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);
        }
        protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {

            // write code for AlertDialog
            return true;
        }

    });
```

You need to override onItemLongClick method also.